# Dirty checking with shared service between controllers, One way works the other does not?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-service

While attempting to answer a question regarding sharing data between two separate controllers I ran into a question .

I usually use services for for this task and began to create a jsfiddle, but I could not get it to work.

After a bit of debugging if I created the properties dynamically in `setActivePersonWorks(person)` the dirty checking worked and the second controller showed the correct value.

If I assigned the value in `setActivePersonDoesNotWork()` it did not.

If I used `$timeout()` I was able to verify that `DataService.badPerson` did indeed contain the correct data.

Am I doing something wrong?  I guess if you do something with `$apply()` it will work correctly, but why does creating the values dynamically cause things to just work?

Working Example:

```
var myTest = angular.module("MyTest", []);
myTest.factory("DataService", function () {
    var People = {
        goodPerson: {},
        badPerson: {},
        setActivePersonWorks: function (person) {
            People.goodPerson.name = person.name;
            People.goodPerson.id = person.id;
        },
        setActivePersonDoesNotWork: function (person) {
            People.badPerson = person;
        }
    };
    return People;
});

function ViewController($scope, DataService, $timeout) {
    $timeout(function () {
        DataService.setActivePersonWorks({
            id: 1,
            name: "Good Mark"
        });
        DataService.setActivePersonDoesNotWork({
            id: 2,
            name: "Bad Mark"
        });
    }, 1000);
}

function DetailController($scope, DataService, $timeout) {
    $scope.goodPerson = DataService.goodPerson;
    $scope.badPerson = DataService.badPerson;

    $timeout(function(){
        $scope.message = "DataService has the value: " + DataService.badPerson.name + " but $scope.badPerson is " + $scope.badPerson.name;
    }, 2000);
}
```

The `<html/>`

```
<div ng-app="MyTest">
    <div ng-controller="ViewController"></div>
    <div ng-controller="DetailController">
         <h1>Works: {{goodPerson.name}}</h1>

         <h1>Does Not Work: {{badPerson.name}}</h1>
        {{message}}
    </div>
</div>
```

[**On jsfiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/markcoleman/gaTxd/1/)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

When Angular sees

```
<h1>Does Not Work: {{badPerson.name}}</h1>
```

it sets up a $watch on object `badPerson`.  Looking at your controller, `$scope.badPerson` is a reference to object `DataService.badPerson`.  All is fine so far... the problem happens here:

```
setActivePersonDoesNotWork: function (person) {
    People.badPerson = person;
}
```

When this function executes, `badPerson` is assigned a new/different object reference, but the controller is still $watching the old/original object reference.

The fix is to use [angular.copy()](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/angular.copy) to update the existing `badPerson` object, rather than assigning a new reference:

```
setActivePersonDoesNotWork: function (person) {
    angular.copy(person, People.badPerson);
}
```

This also explains why `setActivePersonWorks()` works -- it does not assign a new object reference.

Comment: Excellent! Thanks for the fix and also the explanation.