# Why does Angular not databind data when an object is copied from another object?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I've created a simple jsfiddle to illustrate my question:

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/martijngr/akRz5/)

Html:

```
<div ng-controller="MyCtrl">   
    <div ng-repeat="p in products">
        <span ng-click="overwrite(p)">{{ p.id }}: {{ p.name }}</span>
    </div>
</div>
```

Javascript:

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp',[]);

function MyCtrl($scope) {

    var products = [{id:1, name:'first'}, {id:2, name:'second'}];
    $scope.products = products;

    var prod = {id: 3, name:'third'};

    $scope.overwrite = function(p){
        p.id = 4;
        p.name = 'forth';

        p = prod; // this doesn't work nor does angular.copy(prod)
    }
}
```

As you can see, when I set the properties by hand, the values are bind. But when I overwrite an object, nothing happens. How is this possible? And what do I have to do when I want to restore an object in it's original state?

Imagine I create a backup object using `var productBackup = angular.copy(product)`. Then I make changes to the original product and later I decide to cancel my changes. I want to do this using `product = productBackup`. But this doesn't work! In this case, do I need to set all the properties by hand like this?

```
product.id = productBackup.id;
product.name = productBackup.name;
etc...
```

Comment: you can also use angular.extend if you want shallow copy instead of deep copy

Answer (score 23, accepted):

If you use `angular.copy(source, destination)` you are able to achieve the desiered effect.

**[updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/markcoleman/akRz5/3/)**

What is happening is that angular is still watching the original `p` reference even after you do the assignment.  If you use `angular.copy()` you are copying the values from `prod` to `p` which angular is watching correctly.

I asked a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16465292/dirty-checking-with-shared-service-between-controllers-one-way-works-the-other) but it dealt with this issue in a shared service.

Comment: Finally! I am trying to get this working for hours! So, the problem had to do with what reference Angular is watching...

Answer (score 3):

I have never worked with AngularJS before, but I think what is going on here is that your parameter `p` is not your simple key/value object but a more complex AngularJS object. By assigning your `prod` to it you are overriding it instead of changing specific parts of the object.

Maybe the following code snippet will help you out:

```
for(var key in prod) {
    p[key] = prod[key];
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer and FYI this did work, but I rather do this the Angular way :), the way Mark suggested.